# AngularJS doesn't play nice with [ ] in form field name

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I'm using AngularJS for validation in a Symfony2 form. The name of the form field is given by Symfony2, in this case, as "license[domain]", and the validation work greats, but AngularJS doesnt look to play nice with the braces in the name.

## Twig:

```
<div class="col-md-12 has-feedback" ng-class="{
    'has-error': !license.{{ form.domain.vars.full_name }}.$valid,
    'has-success': license.{{ form.domain.vars.full_name }}.$valid
     }">   
     {{ form_widget(form.domain, {
         'attr': {
                 'ng-model': "licenseDomain",
                 'class': "form-control",
                 'ng-pattern': "/^[0-9a-z-]+$/"
                  }
         }) }}
     <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true" ng-class="{'glyphicon-ok': licenseForm.{{ form.domain.vars.full_name}}.$valid,
'glyphicon-remove': !licenseForm.{{ form.domain.vars.full_name }}.$valid }"></span>

{% verbatim %}
<tt>{{ license }}</tt><br/><br/>
<tt>license.{% endverbatim %}{{ form.domain.vars.full_name }}{% verbatim %}.$valid = {{license.{% endverbatim %}{{ form.domain.vars.full_name }}{% verbatim %}.$valid }}</tt><br/>
<tt>{% endverbatim %}{{ form.domain.vars.full_name }}{% verbatim %}.$valid = {{{% endverbatim %}{{ form.domain.vars.full_name }}{% verbatim %}.$valid }}</tt><br/>
<tt>license.domain.$valid = {{license.domain.$valid }}</tt><br/>
<tt>license.licenseDomain.$valid = {{license.licenseDomain.$valid }}</tt><br/>
<tt>license.$valid = {{license.$valid}}</tt><br/>
{% endverbatim %}
</div>
```

## Rendered TT section

```
<tt class="ng-binding">
    {"$error":{"required":[{"$validators":{},"$asyncValidators":{},"$parsers":[],"$formatters":[null],"$viewChangeListeners":[],"$untouched":true,"$touched":false,"$pristine":true,"$dirty":false,"$valid":false,"$invalid":true,"$error":{"required":true},"$name":"license[domain]","$options":null}]},"$name":"license","$dirty":false,"$pristine":true,"$valid":false,"$invalid":true,"$submitted":false,
         "license[domain]":{"$validators":{},"$asyncValidators":{},"$parsers":[],"$formatters":[null],"$viewChangeListeners":[],"$untouched":true,"$touched":false,"$pristine":true,"$dirty":false,"$valid":false,"$invalid":true,"$error":{"required":true},"$name":"license[domain]","$options":null}}
</tt><br><br>    
<tt class="ng-binding">license.license[domain].$valid = </tt><br>
<tt class="ng-binding">license[domain].$valid = </tt><br><tt class="ng-binding">license.domain.$valid = </tt><br>
<tt class="ng-binding">license.licenseDomain.$valid = </tt><br>
<tt class="ng-binding">license.$valid = false</tt><br></div>
```

The validation works perfect, but not the reference to the field. As you can see, the last TT renders license.$valid to false and the first one (the license dump) shows a "license[domain]" object, but none of the ways I tried to reference it in between worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to reference it with **[] instead of .** and **quoting** it.

***PHEW....***

## TWIG:

```
<tt>license["{% endverbatim %}{{ form.domain.vars.full_name }}{% verbatim %}"].$valid = {{license["{% endverbatim %}{{ form.domain.vars.full_name |e }}{% verbatim %}"].$valid }}</tt><br/>
```

## Rendered TT:

```
<tt class="ng-binding">license["license[domain]"].$valid = true</tt>
```

Looks very ugly, though... :(